# using angular flex layout with angular material grid list

Tags: angular, list, grid, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

angular-material provides decent grid list and layout but missing flex layout to adopt to different device, in other hand  angular flex layout gives better flexible view management to different devices but the drawback is we cannot tell flex layout how much column and row space each list item can take, to bring list item to next row we have to keep it in separate container.

I have tried using both to gather but when I bind `[fxLayout]` `[fxLayout.xs]` to a function to get the device state, when I minimize the window size `[fxLayout.xs]` not triggering dynamically upon minimizing the window.

it would be great if someone could solve this, thanks in advance

```ts
export class TopicsComponent {
topics = [
      { title: 'Example', colspan: 2, colspanalt: 7, rowspan: 1, color: '#ffa726', font: '#607d8b', order: '1' }
]

 updateLayout(layout) {
    if (layout === 'fxLayout') {
     this.layoutDesktop = true;
      this.layoutMobile = false;
      return ('column');
    } else if (layout === 'fxLayoutXs') {
      this.layoutMobile = true;
      this.layoutDesktop = false;
      return ('column');
    }
  }
  updateColspan(topic) {
    if (this.layoutDesktop === false ) {
      return (topic.colspan);
    } else if ( this.layoutMobile === true) {
      return (topic.colspanalt);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-card [fxLayout]="updateLayout('fxLayout')" [fxLayout.xs]="updateLayout('fxLayoutXs')" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
      <mat-grid-list [cols]="7" rowHeight="1:1" gutterSize="8px">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let topic of topics" [style.background]="topic.color" [style.color]="topic.font"
        [rowspan]="topic.rowspan" [colspan]="updateColspan(topic)">{{topic.title}}</mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </mat-card>
```